# Number of edges in an undirected graph

Tags: data-structures, graph

Given an adjacency list representation for an undirected graph. Write a function to count the number of edges in the undirected graph.

I know the number of edges in an undirected graph is n(n-1)/2 but I don't know how to write a function for that.

Considering that I've a list and using that I'll be counting the number of edges. How should I start?

Comment: There is not a single possible adjacency list representation for an undirected graph. What sort is yours? Moreover, number of edges in an undirected graph can be anything between 0 to n(n-1)/2.

Answer (score 3):

`n(n-1)/2` is the maximum number of edges in a simple undirected graph, not the number of edges for every such graph.

Given that you have an adjacency list representation, let it be the case that vertices `u` and `v` have an edge between them. Then, `v` will appear in the adjacency list of `u` and `u` will appear in the adjacency list of `v`. This is true for any `u` and `v`.

Hence, if you count the total number of entries of all the elements in the adjacency list of each vertex, the result will be twice the number of edges in the graph. Dividing this value by two will give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

> I know the number of edges in an undirected graph is n(n-1)/2 but I don't know how to write a function for that.

The **maximum** number of edges in undirected graph is n(n-1)/2.
not only number of edges.

Suppose the povided array is.

[image]

```
0[1,2,3]
1[0,2]
2[0,1,4]
3[0]
4[2]
```

then number of edges will be. #java

```
for (ArrayList<Integer> verts : adj) {
            sumOfVert += verts.size();
        }
return sumOfVert/2;// Output will be 5;
```